# Understanding a "Thing" in AWS IoT under development stage

Tags: amazon-web-services

When we log in to our developer account for AWS IoT, we have the option to register a "Thing"

[image]

So we registered a test device, named TestDevice. Then we downloaded the device program package generated from the link, Connect a device(located on top right corner).

[image]

This is the package that we downloaded

[image]

After we ran this package under in a Mac, we were able to receive the messages sent by the AWS IoT platform.

So, we think that this means that the TestDevice(simulated by Mac) is successfully connected to the AWS IoT server。

However, this is just one device. If our clients buy our TestDevice for instance. Then how would each device register itself to the AWS IoT platform?

Then what is the purpose of registering the device during development stage? Is it just for testing purpose?

It's really confusing.